# what is the limit of $\frac1{n+1}$ as $n\to\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, alternative-proof

So far, 
I'ave used the squeeze theorem with functions $\frac1n$ and $-\frac1n$, and so got the limit $0$, but the answer is supposedly infinity... which makes little sense to me.

Comment: And it makes *no* sense to me.

Comment: Are you talking about $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{n+1}$$?

Comment: Or is it supposed to be $$\lim_{n\to-1}\frac1{n+1}$$?

Comment: lim n-> infinity 1/(n+1)

Comment: sorry i can't get the format right ._.

Comment: Then it is not $0$. How is the answer supposed to be $\infty$?

Comment: that's what i could like to know

Comment: @Cookiedough Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is correct

$$-\frac1n\le \frac1{n+1}\le \frac1n$$

then conclude by squeeze theorem noting that the LHS and RHS both tend to zero.

As an alternative you can also observe that

$$0\le \frac1{n+1}\le \frac1n$$

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1}{n+1}}$ try to think about how $\frac{1}{n+1}$ acts for really big values of $n$, whereas if you have $lim_{n\rightarrow 0}{\frac{1}{n+1}}$ try to compute  $\frac{1}{n+1}$ when $n$ is a number really close to $0$.